# Avoid display plain PHP code on CentOS AWS EC2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, centos, centos7

I am using Amazon EC2, CentOS 7 x64_86, 1GB RAM.

(1) Run command

```
php -v
```

result

```
PHP 7.0.24 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2017 10:10:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

(2) Run command

```
httpd -v
```

result

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

(3) Run command

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
```

Result

```
#
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome" page if there
# is no default index page present for the root URL.  To disable the
# Welcome page, comment out all the lines below.
#
# NOTE: if this file is removed, it will be restored on upgrades.
#
#<LocationMatch "^/+$">
#    Options -Indexes
#    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
#</LocationMatch>

<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

How to fix it?

Comment: (Indeed, I don't need virtual host at this time, because server has small RAM) and I use PHP 7.

Comment: OK ... so the DirectoryIndex goes in main Apache config instead of vhost config file. PHP part should not change, just find the appropriate `LoadModule *php*` as I described. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think must install connector between Apache with PHP7, like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-update-php-7-on-centos-rhel-7 but I still don't success.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually seeing 2 different problems.

#### Problem 1

Seeing a directory listing, instead of returning `index.php`.  This must be because you have no [`DirectoryIndex`](/etc/httpd/sites-available) specified.  Check your vhost config (something like `/etc/httpd/sites-available/your-site.conf` *not* `welcome.conf`), and add one inside the vhost block, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    // ... rest of your config
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Problem 2

Apache is showing the contents of `index.php` instead of processing it.  This means PHP support is not enabled.

- Look for `LoadModule` in your Apache config, and make sure some variation of `php` is there, eg `LoadModule php5_module`, and it is not commented out.
- Check you have a MIME type configured in Apache config, eg `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`, and it is not commented out.

References for this problem:

[PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

[HTTPd shows PHP code instead of executing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57547/httpd-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it)

Comment: I see you were looking at `welcome.conf` - you should be editing your vhost config.  I updated my answer.